# Usar JPA en intellij Community

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Soy nuevo en esto de Spring y quiero empezar con Spring Data JPA y no sé como hacerlo con el IDE intelllij Idea porque no me aparece ninguna opcion como lo tiene Netbeans.

¿Cómo puedo añadir jpa a mi proyecto o se debe añadir desde el principio? He intentado descargar un pluggin pero no me sirve, debo ingresar al pom.xml y al meta-inf?

Answer (score 0):

En **`IntelliJ Idea Community`** cuando seleccionas la opción de crear un proyecto utilizando el generador de Spring Initializr te me muestra un mensaje indicando que debes adquirir la version de pago de **`IntelliJ Idea`**.

**Solución Facíl**

Ingresa a la pagina de [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte izquierda seleccionas y llenas las opciones según tus requisitos posterior a eso en la parte de `Dependencies` das clic en **`ADD DEPENDENCIES`** ahí debes escribir `JPA`, da un clic sobre el recuadro verde.

**`Nota:`** Puedes agregar mas dependencias de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe de quedar similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación en la parte inferior de la página da un clic en `GENERATE`, se descargara un archivo comprimido, descomprime el archivo "es una carpeta con varios archivos".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde `IntelliJ Idea` abre la carpeta que descomprimiste, de forma automáticamente IntelliJ cargara las dependencias.